# Codemirror Autocomplete Remove Global Suggestions

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#d956c96bdee0cdd1ce9193aee78353ac

Does anyone know of an effective way to remove some of the global variables out of Codemirror's Autocomplete?

For example StyleFix, PrefixFree, Html2Jade, etc: should not be visible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is its summary: (from https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_javascript-hint)

> This will simply use the JavaScript environment that the editor runs in as a source of information about objects and their properties.

And related source code:

```
var found = [], start = token.string, global = options && options.globalScope || window;
```

and

```
function gatherCompletions(obj) {
  if (typeof obj == "string") forEach(stringProps, maybeAdd);
  else if (obj instanceof Array) forEach(arrayProps, maybeAdd);
  else if (obj instanceof Function) forEach(funcProps, maybeAdd);
  for (var name in obj) maybeAdd(name);//important
}
```

(from https://mikethedj4.github.io/kodeWeave/editor/libraries/codemirror/addon/hint/javascript-hint.js)

In which `obj` is `global`.

So if you want to *remove some of the global variables*
, just modify the `globalScope` param.

Change this line:

```
CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(cm,null, {completeSingle: false});
```

to

```
var scope={};
var preventList=['StyleFix', 'PrefixFree', 'Html2Jade','alert'];// map is better
for(var i in window){
  if(preventList.indexOf(i)===-1){
    scope[i]=window[i]
  }
}
CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(cm,null, {completeSingle: false,globalScope:scope});
```

Live demo here:
https://mikethedj4.github.io/kodeWeave/editor/#cf4c4aa884b6ddb30c4ac79dd8bf3997